# How can I fix my Raycast so it returns true when there are tiles beneath the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

In my platformer, my player clamps onto the sides of tiles and hooks there. I want to remove this so the player can't clamp onto the sides of any tiles on my Tilemap.

In my movement script, I tried to add a `Raycast` that shoots downwards. I excepted it to work but instead it isn't letting me jump and is playing the falling animation which only occurs if my `isGrounded` variable is set to `false`. I am suspecting something is wrong with my `Raycast`.

Here is the code:

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
         RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit)) 
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject == floor) 
            {
                isGrounded = true;
            }
        }
  
    }
```

*NOTE: the `floor` variable is the tilemap*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need a raycast in your `OnCollisionEnter2D`.

To check if Ground is below you make sure your tiles have a collider set.

Then, add a new tag and name it "Ground."

Assign the new tag to the tilemap.

Use the new tag to check if your collision has it.

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
     if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground")
         isGrounded = true;
}
```

Secondly, if you don't want the first method, in 2D physics, you'd use `Physics2D.RayCast`
[> see reference <](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)

```cs
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up);

if (hit != null) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 3D raycast. It should be physics2D. [Reference Raycast 2D Code](https://vionixstudio.com/2020/12/28/unity-raycast/#Unity_Raycast_in_2D). Add a debug log statement to check if the raycast is executed. Also you are raycasting to an infinite length. Restrict it to say 1 unit below the player.

You can check out this video on [how to ground check](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxCVHBMdTWo) in a proper way.